# How to read in .edges file in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I downloaded a network object from the network repository (http://networkrepository.com/actor-movie.php). But I failed to load this .edges file in R with **igraph::read.graph** with the following errors:

```
dat <- read.graph("actor-movie.edges")

Error in read.graph.edgelist(file, ...) : 
  At foreign.c:101 : parsing edgelist file failed, Parse error
```

Does anyone have an idea how to load this network in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that the error with `igraph::read_graph` is due to the separator -- in the file it is comma separated but the function expects whitespace for `format="edgelist"`.  However, we can just read the fie in as a dataframe using standard import tools. Then `igraph` functions can be used to form the graph.

```
# download
pth <- "http://nrvis.com/download/data/misc/actor-movie.zip"
download.file(pth, destfile = "actor-movie.zip")

# see file names
unzip("actor-movie.zip", list = TRUE)

# unzip
unz <- unzip("actor-movie.zip", "actor-movie.edges")

# quick look : looks like edge list
readLines(unz, n=10)

# skip first line to avoid % bipartite unweighted" 
dat <- read.table(unz, skip=1, sep=",")

# look
head(dat)
str(dat)

# load as a graph
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(dat)
g
```